# Adding and removing elements in a user defined Java Doubly LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm studying for an exam I have next week and I was hoping somebody could help me out when it comes to adding and removing elements from a doubly linked list.  The logic makes sense to me, unfortunately I am not that great at coding yet (only my second computer science course).  I have looked all over the web and in my text as well, but I can't seem to find an example close enough to my problem.  Below I will post what my professor is asking me to accomplish, as well as my current code.  Thank you in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

I was having issues with adding as well, but somebody was able to help me out, however I'm still having issues with my remove method.  I find it odd that my professor has a remove method with a return type other than void.  Can somebody explain this?  Anyways, my updated code is below.

**From the professor:**

Fill in the missing code in CS401DblLinkedListImpl.java as 
indicated in the class lecture.

To test your code, create a doubly linked list and enter the 
following elements of type String in it:

Bill, Rohan, James, Krishna, Javier, Lisa

(a) Print the linked list starting at the beginning.

(b) Print the linked list starting at the end.

(c) Remove Bill and print the linked list starting from beginning.

(d) Remove Lisa and print the linked list starting from end.

(e) Remove Krishna and print the linked list starting from the 
beginning.

This following set of code is my user defined class and the methods I will be testing are boolean add(E e), E remove(int n), void print_from_beginning(), and void print_from_end():

```
package week6;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class CS401DblLinkedListImpl<E> //implements CS401CollectionInterface<E> 
{
   private LinkEntry<E> head = null;
   private LinkEntry<E> tail = null;
   private int size = 0;

   public CS401DblLinkedListImpl()
   {
      head = tail = null;
   }

   public boolean is_empty()
   {
      if (head == null) 
          return true;

      return false;
   }

   public int size()
   {
       int count = 0;
       for (LinkEntry<E> current = head; current != null; current = current.next)
           count++;
       return count;
   }

   /*
    * Add e to the end of the doubly linked list.
    * Returns true - if e was successfully added, false otherwise.
    */
   public boolean add(E e)
   {   
      LinkEntry<E> new_element = new LinkEntry<E>();
      new_element.element = e;

          if (head == null)
          {
          new_element.next = head;
          head = new_element;
          tail = head;
      }
      else
      {
          tail.next = new_element;
          new_element.previous = tail;
          tail = new_element;
      }
      return true;
   }

   /*
    * Remove the nth element in the list.  The first element is element 1.
    * Return the removed element to the caller.
    */
   public E remove(int n)
   {
      LinkEntry<E> current = new LinkEntry<E>();
      int i = 0;

      while (n == i++)
      {
          current.previous.next = current.next;
          if (current.next == null)
          {
              current.next.previous = current.previous;
          }
      }
      return (E) current;
   }

  /*
   * Print the doubly linked list starting at the beginning.
   */
   public void print_from_beginning()
   {
      LinkEntry<E> current = new LinkEntry<E>();
      for (current = head; current != null; current = current.next)
      {
          System.out.print(current.element + " ");
      }
   }

   /*
    * Print the doubly linked list starting the end.
    */
   public void print_from_end()
   {
      LinkEntry<E> current = new LinkEntry<E>();
      for (current = tail; current != null; current = current.previous)
      {
          System.out.print(current.element + " ");
      }
   }

   /* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   /* Inner classes                                                      */
   protected class LinkEntry<E>
   {
      protected E element;
      protected LinkEntry<E> next;
      protected LinkEntry<E> previous;

      protected LinkEntry() { element = null; next = previous = null; }
   }
   /* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
   protected class CS401DblLinkedListImplIterate<E> implements Iterator<E>
   {

       protected LinkEntry<E> next;

       protected CS401DblLinkedListImplIterate()
       {
           next = (LinkEntry<E>) head;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean hasNext() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public E next() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void remove() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
      }
} /* CS401LinkedListImpl<E> */
```

Below is my main class where I test the methods:

```
package week6;

import java.util.*;

public class App {

    public static <E> void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Part 1 of lab 6: Testing CS401DblLinkedListImpl
     */
    System.out.println("Testing Lab 6: Part 1...");
    CS401DblLinkedListImpl<String> list = new CS401DblLinkedListImpl<String>();

    list.add("Bill");
    list.add("Rohan");
    list.add("James");
    list.add("Krishna");
    list.add("Javier");
    list.add("Lisa");

    System.out.println("List size after all names are added: " + list.size());

    //a. Print the linked list starting at the beginning.
    System.out.println("\nPrint the linked list starting at the beginning:");
    list.print_from_beginning();

    //b. Print the linked list starting at the end.
    System.out.println("\nPrint the linked list starting at the end:");
    list.print_from_end();

    //c. Remove Bill and print the linked list starting from beginning.
    System.out.println("\nRemove Bill and print the linked list starting from beginning:");
    list.remove(0);
    list.print_from_beginning();

    //d. Remove Lisa and print the linked list starting from end.
    System.out.println("\nRemove Lisa and print the linked list starting from end:");
    list.remove(4);
    list.print_from_end();

    //e. Remove Krishna and print the linked list starting from the beginning.
    System.out.println("\nRemove Krishna and print the linked list starting from the beginning:");
    list.remove(2);
    list.print_from_beginning();

    System.out.println("\nList size: " + list.size());
    }
}
```

Finally, below is what I get when I run my program:

```
Testing Lab 6: Part 1...
List size after all names are added: 6

Print the linked list starting at the beginning:
Bill Rohan James Krishna Javier Lisa 
Print the linked list starting at the end:
Lisa Javier Krishna James Rohan Bill 
Remove Bill and print the linked list starting from beginning:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at week6.CS401DblLinkedListImpl.remove(CS401DblLinkedListImpl.java:67)
    at week6.App.main(App.java:34)
```

FYI, CS401DblLinkedListImpl.java:67 refers to the following line of code in my remove method:

```
      current.previous.next = current.next;
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.  I feel like I'm somewhat close to the answer, it just needs some clarifying.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will not handle removing index 0.

```
LinkEntry<E> current = head;
if (n == 0) {
    // something like this maybe...
    head = head.next;
    if (head != null) { head.previous = null; }
    return current;
}
```

You start with i = 0 but do an i++ so you're at head, but with an index of 1.

Also your remove logic looks odd to me.

```
 current.previous.next == current (is true)
 current.next.previous == current (is true)
```

so it should be something like:

```
if (n == i++) {
    // We're at the spot so let's remove it.
    current.previous.next = current.next;
    if (current.next != null) { current.next.previous = current.previous; }
    return current;
}
```

Also I believe you add logic is wrong too, should be like.

```
LinkEntry<E> new_element = new LinkEntry<E>();
new_element.element = e;
if (head == null) {
    head = new_element;
    tail = head;
} else {
    tail.next = new_element;
    new_element.previous = tail;
    tail = new_element;
}

size++;  // You don't use size it looks like...  and your size starts at 1 which is 
         // wrong, it should start at 0 since it's empty, also remove would have to
         // update size.
return true;
```

Comment: Everything except the remove method is working now.

Comment: Sorry, I see the change now. check if current.previous is null it seems.